# How to insert custom IDs in to eclipse template - CDT

Tags: eclipse, templates, eclipse-cdt

For the C++ header and source default templates, the `${filecomment}` template inserts the `${user}` variable for the Author comment. But I want to use my full name and email instead for the Author comment. Is there a way to do this without writing code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for Indigo I have it here:
Window->Preferences->Code Style->Code Templates->Comments->Files